# Hook "form_views_exposed_form_alter" is called multiply times

Tags: views, 8

I would like to understand why `form_views_exposed_form_alter` is called multiply times.

There is just one view, also there is just one exposed filter. However the hook is getting called twice.

```
xyz_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
   dpm('inner');
}
```

Is there any value I can use for an if statement to run my script just once?

Comment: It's called once while being built, and once again while being validated/submitted. Sometimes in the same request (when you've submitted a form but the page you wind up on also renders that form). That's normal behaviour

Comment: For an if statement you can use $form_state. When there are no user input values you know it's the first form build.

Comment: great answer.... of course makes sense.

Comment: They seem to be identical.

Comment: Both returned arrays do not contain the changes made via the hook

Comment: I wouldn't worry about multiple calls, important is only if you build a fresh form or rebuild a form and react on user input. Multiple calls only matter if you use the alter hook in a wrong way as a trigger, then you probably need to find a different hook/event.

Comment: thing is that I am collecting data from the database... so this request is made twice quite dirty.

Comment: can I collect the data in an earlier hook + attaching it to the view or form element as variable? That would allow the exposed_form_alter hook to use the already requested data instead of collecting it.... twice

Comment: OK, we had this discussion a few month ago, can't find it. Then I recommended to refactor the database call in a service to cache the values statically in the service properties.

Comment: ok .. comes close to what I just asked. Actually I have written a module that offers custom storage controllers with singletons. Should also work.

Comment: Yes, a service is a singleton.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/structure-of-a-service-file for more information about how to implement custom services

Comment: OK,  I meant a service is a singleton unless you use `scope: prototype` or `shared: false`.